# How to add a display filter in Alpine.JS like in Vue?

Tags: javascript, datetime, alpine.js

How can I show date-time in a human-readable format in `Alpine.js`? I would add a filter in Vuejs to do the same and looking for a similar solution in `Alpine.js`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Data time display in AlpineJS</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.3.0/alpine.js"
        integrity="sha512-nIwdJlD5/vHj23CbO2iHCXtsqzdTTx3e3uAmpTm4x2Y8xCIFyWu4cSIV8GaGe2UNVq86/1h9EgUZy7tn243qdA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div x-data="mdata()">
        <h3 x-text="name"></h3>
        <h3 x-text="created_on"></h3>
    </div>
    <script>
        const mdata = () => {
            return {
                name: "Carpet",
                created_on: Date.now(),
            };
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yesterday, I faced the same issue and overcame it by using javascript. You can use it like this: Date.now().toLocaleDateString()

Comment: I found a better way to do it, this issue was already solved in the issue list of `Alpine.js` `Github` repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After delving into the issues of `Alpine.js` `Github` repository, learnt that it is possible to call a function in `x-text` directive as **Alpine.js can access any functions defined in the global scope as well as in the component scope.**

For further details look at [here](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/57#issuecomment-575924872) and [here](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/803#issuecomment-703562308)

Declared the following function:

```
var date_format = function (value) {
    if (value) {
        return dayjs(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
    }
    else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And referred it like this in `x-text`:

```
<div x-data="mdata()">
    <h3 x-text="name"></h3>
    <h3 x-text="date_format(created_on)"></h3>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Data time display in AlpineJS</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.3.0/alpine.js"
        integrity="sha512-nIwdJlD5/vHj23CbO2iHCXtsqzdTTx3e3uAmpTm4x2Y8xCIFyWu4cSIV8GaGe2UNVq86/1h9EgUZy7tn243qdA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div x-data="mdata()">
        <h3 x-text="name"></h3>
        <h3 x-text="date_format(created_on)"></h3>
    </div>
    <script>
        const mdata = () => {
            return {
                name: "Carpet",
                created_on: Date.now(),
            };
        };
        var date_format = function (value) {
            if (value) {
                return dayjs(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
            }
            else {
                return value;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```